# zf2/zf3 how to validate dependent inputs in collection's fieldset?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I have a form. The form has a `Collection` whose target element is a fieldset with a checkbox and a couple of text fields. The fieldset attached as the target element to `Collection` looks like this (simplified to avoid too much code):

```
class AFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(HydratorInterface $hydrator) 
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->setHydrator($hydrator)
            ->setObject(new SomeObject());

        $this->add([
            'type' => Hidden::class,
            'name' => 'id',
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'type' => Checkbox::class,
            'name' => 'selectedInForm',
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'type' => Text::class,
            'name' => 'textField1',
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'type' => Text::class,
            'name' => 'textField2',
        ]);
    }
    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return [
            'selectedInForm' => [
                'required' => false,
                'continue_if_empty' => true,
                'validators' => [
                    ['name' => Callback::class // + options for the validator],
                ],
            ],
            'id' => [
                'requred' => false,
                'continue_if_empty' => true,
            ],
            'textField1' => [
                'required' => false,
                'continue_if_empty' => true,
                'validators' => [
                    ['name' => SomeValidator::class],
                ],
            ],
            'textField2' => [
                'required' => true,
                'validators' => [
                    ['name' => SomeValidator::class],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    }
}
```

I'd like to validate `textField1` and `textField2` based on if `selectedInForm` checkbox is checked in the form.

How could I do this?

I though of using a `Callback` validator for `selectedInForm` checkbox like this:

```
'callback' => function($value) {
    if ($value) {
        $this->get('textField1')->isValid();
        // or $this->get('textField1')->getValue() and do some validation with it
    }
}
```

but the problem with it is that, for some reason, the posted value of `textField1` value isn't attached to the input yet. Same is true for `textField2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two option is available. One is where you started, with callback validators.

The other one is to write a custom validator, and to make it reusable I recommend this solution.

```
<?php

use Zend\Validator\NotEmpty;

class IfSelectedInFormThanNotEmpty extends NotEmpty
{
    public function isValid($value, array $context = null): bool
    {
        if (! empty($context['selectedInForm']) && $context['selectedInForm']) {
            return parent::isValid($value);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then you can use it as every other validator:

```
'textField2' => [
    'required' => true,
    'validators' => [
        ['name' => IfSelectedInFormThanNotEmpty::class],
    ],
],
```

This may not be your exact case, but I hope it helped to get the idea.

You may define options to make it more reusable with a configurable conditional field in `public function __construct($options = null)`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, how to get the `$context` variable into the `IfSelectedInFormThanNotEmpty::isValid()` when you validate the form in the controller? i suppose i'll have to rewrite the `Form`'s `isValid()` method too. is this so?

Comment: Ohh, of course not. Actually it's an undocumented feature I had a talk about with zf devs. The context should be already there. When you call the `Form::isValid` it calls the ValidatorChain's isValid which iterates through the defined validators with the value and the context.  So you just place this new validator to your validators list:
`'validators' => [ [ 'name' => Your\Namespace\IfSelectedInFormThanNotEmpty::class] ]`
As I mentioned in the answer. Or do you have any further complications?

Comment: hmm, strange, but i don't see an injection of `$context` variable in the constructor of `AbstractValidator`. i'll give it a try and get back to you. +1ed your answer for now. :-)

Comment: It shouldn't be in the constructor but in the isValid().
Zend\InputFilter\Input class' isValid method is what the validation process calls. There you can catch it with a debugger for example :)